# How can I make the entire body a textField in a Flutter Scaffold widget?

Tags: flutter, mobile, textfield

I am making a notes app with markdown support and trying to make the body of my `Scaffold()` widget a text field. How can I style it so that the entire body is editable?

Answer (score 0):

Although not very elegant, a workaround to achieve this is the use the `maxLines` property of the `TextField` `Widget`:

```
@override                                                    
Widget build(BuildContext context) {                         
   return SafeArea(                                           
     child: Scaffold(                                         
       body: SafeaArea(
          child: Container(                                       
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,          
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20), // small padding to improve the UI 
            child: TextField(                                    
              maxLines: 100,                                     
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,             
            ), 
         ), 
       ), 
     ), 
  ); 
}
```